# CodeLite error while compiling library project

Tags: codelite

Im trying to compile static library project with CodeLite and getting error:

```
ar rcus ./Debug/libtestlib.a @"testlib.txt" 
ar: @testlib.txt: No such file or directory
```

But i have file testlib.txt. When i inspect exported makefile i see:

```
$(AR) $(ArchiveOutputSwitch)$(OutputFile) @$(ObjectsFileList) $(ArLibs)
```

For me it is strange to see there @ symbol near ObjectsFileList. How should i compile static library project in CodeLite ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@"testlib.txt"` is a way of letting the linker (or `ar` in your case) to read the object list from a file and not from a command line, this is done because on some OS, there is a limitation on the input string that a program can accept from the command line.

Usually this is not a problem ( you did not mention what is your OS and CodeLite version ) but if it is a problem (like in your case), you can disable this from CodeLite's menu bar:

`Settings -> Build Settings -> Compilers -> <Your Compiler Name> -> Advanced`

and Uncheck the option:
"Pass object list to the linker via file" and your problems will be gone

FYI:
I only seen this error on OSX, is this the case here?

Eran

Comment: Yes i'm having this trouble on OSX. I'll try this solution next time i'm able to get to my Mac

Comment: I have this problem on OSX.  It seems the *.txt file required is created but not where the linker is looking for it (?).  Changing the setting as you described did fix the problem.  +1, thank you.